# Acess teamcity artifact path in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, deployment, msbuild, teamcity

I recently configured a buildserver which compiles and builds my C# solution just fine.
I'm building it with MSBuild by the way, no Visual Studio is installed.
So now, I want to deploy my /bin folder to another server.

So now to my Problem:
At the build config I've set the follow artifact path:

```
src\PROJECTNAME\bin\Debug => deploy.zip
```

The location of the zip is: 
`C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\.artifacts_cache\localhost_9191\httpAuth\repository\download\CONFIGNAME\8.tcbuildid`, and there is my `deploy.zip`.

The thing is that I can't change the left part (`C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\.artifacts_cache\localhost_9191\httpAuth\repository\download\CONFIGNAME`), just the right part apparently.

Even if I set the `<teamcity Data directory>` it doesn't solve my problem, as the deep structure and variable folder name (8.tcbuild) still exists, just at another location.

So, apparently I can't create an artifact zip outside the Data folder. 
But there has to be a way to access the path, isn't it? I can't find a parameter, which I could use for a PowerShell script.

Could you show me a solution, how I can generate an artifact zip by TeamCity and then access and use the zip by PowerShell and, for example, copy it to another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Artefact dependencies between two Configurations.

1. A first configuration "Packaging" style, with an artifact rule, to create a file : `deploy.zip`
2. A second configuration "Deploying" style, with an artifacts dependencies on `*.zip` from `Packaging` which will run your PowerShell.

You can specify the path of your input artifacts inside the second configuration in order to use it inside your powershell.

ie:

## Artifacts Dependencies

```
*.zip => DeployData/
```

## PowerShell Script

```
 Copy-Item DeployData/*.zip DestinationFolder
```